# Sql Server SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to use `sp_executesql`, but I have a certain question, that although I researched I found a possible solution.

In some part of the SQL script I have the following statement:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          @sql_troca, 
          N '@CD_ITEM char(7)', 
          @cd_item = @cd_item
```

And it works.

But in line with the parameters

```
@cd_item = @cd_item
```

I wanted to dynamically build, already have strategic statement that looks like this:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
          @sql_troca, 
          N '@CD_ITEM char(7)', 
          N ' @cd_item = @cd_item '
```

but when running, an error shows up:

> The parameterized query @CD_ITEM char(7)

How can I pass the parameters as a string? or is there really no possibility

Comment: THat's not the whole error message .... please post the **complete and exact** error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to pass the literal string `' @cd_item = @cd_item '` as the value of the first parameter. The first parameter is defined as `char(7)`, and you're trying to pass it a 20-character string, which is why you're getting an error message.

However, increasing the length of the parameter to 20 won't fix the problem; you'll just be passing the literal string as the value of the first parameter, when you actually want to pass the value of a local variable.

There is no way to pass the parameters as a string. That's not how [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx) works.

Comment: ok .. I understand ... 
Is there any other way so I can get around this? 

tried using the exec (@ sql) all forms, but without success.

Comment: just so you understand, I build everything at runtime. So I wanted to have a solution that worked with string type.

Comment: @JoséLuiz: Not that I've seen. You'll just have to pass all the parameters to `sp_executesql`, whether or not the query uses them.